# Disable 2nd dropdown option based on first dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two dynamic dropdowns but both dropdown's value and options are same. What I want that if user select 'apple' from first dropdown then the second dropdown's apple option will be disabled (using javascript). In short user can not select same value from both.

```
//first drop down
<select name="fruit1">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>

//second dropdown  
<select name="fruit2">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>
```

I have tried with jQuery:

```
function witness()
{
    var op=document.getElementById("witness1").value;
    $('option[value='+op+']').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

But with this both dropdown's value are disabled and if I select mango then apple will not enabled it remains disabled. I know I did not pass id so both dropdown value are disabled but where should i pass ?

If user select apple then in second dropdown apple will be disabled, I want to do this using Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: see my edited code !

Comment: name property is double given in your code.

Comment: You should try jqueys $('#YourSelect').change(function(){alert('first select changed');});

Comment: I'd suggest you let the user not select that option by throwing a message rather than disabling options.

Comment: sorry i have changed the name. But i want to disable second dropdown's value.

Comment: @|shetty| that's good idea i did it before but client don't want that thing.

Comment: Well, then, you have a problem. Imagine you select option1 from select1 and option1 in select2 is disabled. Then, you changed your mind and selected option2 from select1 and option2 in select2 is disabled too! Now, select 2 is useless!

Comment: To answer "where do I pass?", one option is `$('[name='fruit2'] option[value='+op+']').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your fast help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

HTML:

```
<select id='fruit1' onchange="witness();">
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>

<select id='fruit2'>
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
function witness(){
    $("#fruit2 option").each(function(){
        if($("#fruit1 option:selected").val() == $(this).val())
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        else
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    });
}
```

You can see a working exemple here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mqjxL4n0/

Comment: Notice that this function also reenables the options from the second select element that are not selected on the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3pfo1d1f/

To get the functionality you're after, you need to hook into the `change` event on the first dropdown, in order to disable the matching element in the second drop-down.

I also initialised the first element in the second dropdown as disabled ( as this chosen by default in the first dropdown)

Used jquery as you are:

HTML:

```
<!-- first dropdown -->
<select id="fruit1">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>

<br /> <br />

<!-- second dropdown -->
<select id="fruit2">
    <option value="1" disabled>Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#fruit1').on( "change", function() {
    var op = $( this ).val();
    $('#fruit2 option').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#fruit2 option[value='+op+']').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

This should still work, no matter how many options you have in both the dropdowns

Comment: Thanks dear... but on first selection it is not working. after that its working perfectly.

Comment: You mean, you want it to automatically select a non-clashing item in the second one as well as just disabling the option? It can do that for sure. https://jsfiddle.net/3pfo1d1f/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="firstselect" id="firstselect">
   <option value="apple">Apple</option>
   <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>

<select name="secondselect" id="secondselect">
   <option value="apple">Apple</option>
   <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#firstselect').change(function(){
         var firstselected = $(this).val();
         if(firstselected ){
             $('#secondselect option').each(function(){
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                if($(this).val()==firstselected )
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
             });
         }
         else {
             $('#secondselect option').each(function(){
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
             });
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you have to add the id to your select or  change idselection to name selection